# how to resolve the following error in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> Error: Can't find variable: navigation

### Login.js file

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Button
} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  // static navigationOptions = {
  //     title: 'login screen',
  //   };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props;
    //var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <View style={styles.logo}>
          <Image
            source={require("../pics/logofinal.png")}
            style={{ width: 380, height: 200 }}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Enter associateID"
            type="email"
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            secureTextEntry
          />
          <Button
            style={styles.btn}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
            title="login"
          ></Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
```

Looks like you should have `navigation` in `props`